# Firefox 17 Add more than one Bookmarks toolbar

Tags: firefox

Does anyone know how I can add more than one bookmarks toolbar? I don't want to add more rows I really want to add a new bookmarks toolbar so I can have another directory there.

I tried googling for this and the only thing I can find is the multirow addon which is not what I want.

Comment: You can have mine; I never use it :P

Comment: Could you create a folder there and use that to separate them?

Comment: @BrianA I could I just hopping there was a way to have more than one toolbar so I can have folders organized